# Helper text not showing in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm building a Sign Up screen and i want to show a helper text on a EditText, i am using material but isn't showing. I've checked the google docs and i think i did nothing bad.
Here's my edittext code

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="164dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createAccountSubTextView">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_login_edittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/gris_oscuro"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:helperText="ddffef"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createAccountSubTextView" />


    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the result
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HObMY.png)

Also i'm trying to remove the white border above the edittext but it's not possible, someone can help me?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `android:background="@null"` it will remove the white line from edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to reproduce content bellow ([here is the doc](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields)) [image]

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:hint="Numéro de téléphone ou Email"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/grey_5"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/spacing_middle"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/spacing_middle"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_phone"
    app:startIconTint="@color/grey_40"
    app:helperText="Veuillez remplir ce champs"
    app:placeholderTextColor="@color/grey_40">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i thought that these parameters had to stay on the edittext and not into the layout. Again, thanks!!